# Multiple variables on one line with same behind =

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm working with JavaScript since 2 weeks and I wanted to make something easier if it were possible.

I got this in my JS:

```
var div0 = document.createElement("div");
var div1 = document.createElement("div");
var div2 = document.createElement("div");
var div3 = document.createElement("div");
var div4 = document.createElement("div");
var div5 = document.createElement("div");
var div6 = document.createElement("div");
var div7 = document.createElement("div");
```

Is there a way to get this all on one line? (Not having to retype the whole thing everytime?) Everything in the line is the same exept for the number behind div.. Isn't the way I do it just a waste of space?

Thanks!

Comment: what are you planning to do with them?

Comment: Creating different divs generated by JS with pictures in it in 1 function! If that makes sense to you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var divs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++ ) {
    divs.push(document.createElement("div"));
}
```

Now each array element inside `divs` will contain different `div` element.

Comment: @user2894386 You are welcome, please don't forget to accept the answer when you can. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This "should" not be done, but the only way i know, with the limitations initialy imposed, to get the same result, 8 variables defined and each referencing a new created div is

```
for ( var i=0; i<8; i++ ) eval('var div'+i+'=document.createElement("div");');
```